# Keep changes in activity even after closing it

Tags: android, listview, button, android-activity

I have a listview which when clicked on listitem opens a new singleitenview activity

The singleitenm view consists of a button which is used to add the corresponding listitem to favorites activity(if not yet added) and changes the button color to yellow indicating it is added to favoorites or else gray if not in favorites

Till here everything works fine but if i close the singleitemview and reopen it the button color changes back to previous color but still in facvorites

What shall i do to  the button color not getting changed

**favbtn of singleitemview activity**

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemButton1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            products=new ArrayList<Product>();
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            String jsonObj = extras.getString("selected item");


            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            try
            {
                Product pro = mapper.readValue(jsonObj, Product.class);

                if (checkFavoriteItem(pro)) {

                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(SingleItemView.this, pro);

                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                                   SingleItemView.this.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(SingleItemView.this, pro);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                                   SingleItemView.this.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {};





        });
```

**onitemclick of my list activity**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            Product pro = productListAdapter.getItem(position);

                            String favimg = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite)).toString();

    try
    {
        String hi = "this is testint";


        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(pro);

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SingleItemView.class);
        intent.putExtra("selected item", jsonInString);


        ;

        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    //  startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {}  



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate()` method of your singleitemview activity, after you inflate the view that has the favorite button, you simply need to check if the item is in favorites and set the button's background color accordingly.

Comment: Checkfavoriteitem() checks whether it is in favourites or not

Comment: Do you call checkFavoriteItem() in onCreate() or onResume(), or just in the onClickListener()? When you resume the application, you need to iterate over all of the list items and set the background color...

Comment: Wherever the button is inflated/created, check the conditions that determine the background color and set it accordingly.  If you do it in `onClickListener()`, it won't persist when you return to the activity.